# Generate PKCS#10 CSR from RSA Private & Public Keys. How?

Tags: rust, openssl, rsa

I am new to Rust and have finally found something to learn from that keeps me interested throughout the steep learning curve; encryption.

I was wondering if Rust is mature enough to produce the same output as the following `openssl` command **but without using** `openssl`.

```bash
sudo openssl req \
    -new \
    -newkey rsa:2048 \
    -nodes \
    -keyout $HOME/www_example_com.key \
    -out $HOME/www_example_com.csr \
    -config /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf \
    -subj "/C=US/ST=Utah/L=Salt Lake City/O=Xmpl, Inc./OU=IT Department/CN=www.example.com/emailAddress=admin@example.com"
```

So far, I have found the creates [Crate rsa](https://docs.rs/rsa/latest/rsa/) & [Struct std::path::Path](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html) which allows me to create RSA Public & Private keys of (n) bits and export them as PEM files.

I then found the [Crate rcgen](https://docs.rs/rcgen/latest/rcgen/) which seems to include [Struct rcgen::CertificateSigningRequest](https://docs.rs/rcgen/latest/rcgen/struct.CertificateSigningRequest.html) and this is where I get lost.

How can I produce the same output as openssl command?

The rust code so far:

```rust
use rsa::{RsaPrivateKey, RsaPublicKey, pkcs1::{EncodeRsaPrivateKey, EncodeRsaPublicKey, LineEnding}};
use std::path::Path;
use rcgen::CertificateSigningRequest;

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let bits = 2048;
    let priv_key = RsaPrivateKey::new(&mut rng, bits).expect("failed to generate a key");
    let pub_key = RsaPublicKey::from(&priv_key);

    // Encode private key to PEM
    // let priv_pem = priv_key.to_pkcs1_pem(LineEnding::LF).expect("failed to encode private key");
    // println!("Private Key PEM:\n{:#?}", priv_pem);

    // Optionally, write to a file
    priv_key.write_pkcs1_pem_file(Path::new("www_example_com_prv.key"), LineEnding::LF).expect("failed to write private key");

    // Encode public key to PEM
    // let pub_pem = pub_key.to_pkcs1_pem(LineEnding::LF).expect("failed to encode public key");
    // println!("Public Key PEM:\n{:#?}", pub_pem);

    // Optionally, write to a file
    pub_key.write_pkcs1_pem_file(Path::new("www_example_com_pub.key"), LineEnding::LF).expect("failed to write public key");

    println!("RSA {}bit Private Key generated.", bits);
    println!("RSA {}bit Public Key generated.", bits);
}
```

Comment: Depending on how you define 'same', except for _very_ old versions (before about 2012) `openssl req -newkey ... -keyout ... -nodes` writes PKCS8-u format (for all types of privatekey) not PKCS1 format (RSA only). These formats are interchangeable in some cases (the PEM labels allow easy recognition) but not in others. `openssl req` doesn't write a publickey file at all, but `openssl` commands that do similarly use 'SPKI' aka X509 or 'PUBKEY' format, not PKCS1. Also the CSR standard is PKCS 10 not PCKS.

Comment: Have you tried https://docs.rs/rcgen/latest/rcgen/struct.Certificate.html#method.from_params ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a CSR with [*rcgen*](https://docs.rs/rcgen/latest/rcgen/) is actually straightforward: you specify the certificate parameters and keys with [`CertificateParams`](https://docs.rs/rcgen/latest/rcgen/struct.CertificateParams.html), create a `Certificate` instance with [`Certificate::from_params()`](https://docs.rs/rcgen/latest/rcgen/struct.Certificate.html#method.from_params) and can use it to create a CSR with [`Certificate#serialize_request_pem()`](https://docs.rs/rcgen/latest/rcgen/struct.Certificate.html#method.serialize_request_pem):

Example:

```rust
use rcgen::{Certificate, CertificateParams, DnType, DistinguishedName, PKCS_RSA_SHA256, KeyPair};

fn main() {
  
  let pkcs8 = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEv...fke4LZo5mOS10
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
  let keypair = KeyPair::from_pem(pkcs8).unwrap();
  let mut distinguished_name = DistinguishedName::new();
  distinguished_name.push(DnType::CountryName, "US");
  distinguished_name.push(DnType::StateOrProvinceName, "Utah");
  distinguished_name.push(DnType::LocalityName, "Salt Lake City");
  distinguished_name.push(DnType::OrganizationName, "Xmpl, Inc.");
  distinguished_name.push(DnType::OrganizationalUnitName, "IT Department");
  distinguished_name.push(DnType::CommonName, "www.example.com");
  distinguished_name.push(DnType::CustomDnType(vec![1, 2, 840, 113549, 1, 9, 1]), "admin@example.com");

  let mut params: CertificateParams = Default::default();
  params.alg = &PKCS_RSA_SHA256;
  params.distinguished_name = distinguished_name;
  params.key_pair = Some(keypair);
 
  let cert: Certificate = Certificate::from_params(params).unwrap();
  println!("{}", cert.serialize_request_pem().unwrap());
}
```

Note that the private key in the above example code must be in PKCS#8 format, whereas your code uses PKCS#1. Switching to PKCS#8 is simple:

```rust
use rsa::{RsaPrivateKey, RsaPublicKey, pkcs8::{EncodePrivateKey, EncodePublicKey, LineEnding}};

fn main() {
  let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
  let bits = 2048;
  let priv_key = RsaPrivateKey::new(&mut rng, bits).expect("failed to generate a key");
  let pub_key = RsaPublicKey::from(&priv_key);

  // Encode private key in PKCS#8 format to PEM                                                                 // added for private key in PKCS#8 format
  let priv_pkcs8_pem = priv_key.to_pkcs8_pem(LineEnding::LF).expect("failed to encode private key");
  println!("Private Key PEM (PKCS#8):\n{:#?}", priv_pkcs8_pem);

  // Encode public key in X.509/SPKI format to PEM                                                              // added for public key in X.509/SPKI format
  let pub_spki_pem = pub_key.to_public_key_pem(LineEnding::LF).expect("failed to encode public key");
  println!("Public Key PEM (X.509/SPKI):\n{:#?}", pub_spki_pem);
}
```

The CSR created in this way corresponds to the CSR created with OpenSSL (v3.0.0).

---

Note: Actually, a new key pair is automatically generated if no key is specified in the certificate parameters. However, this does not work for RSA, but only for ECDSA and EdDSA, see the [source code](https://docs.rs/rcgen/latest/src/rcgen/key_pair.rs.html#243). For this reason, for RSA an existing key pair must be applied or a key pair must be generated beforehand.